# Writing a Socket.IO server in C++

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I want to write a C++ server that uses the same wire format as Socket.IO. I found [the `gevent-socketio` packet codec for the wire](https://github.com/abourget/gevent-socketio/blob/master/socketio/packet.py) but I can't find the corresponding client codec.

The packets get encoded like this: `5:1+::{"name": "tobi"}`

The [`socket.io-protocol`#Packet](https://github.com/automattic/socket.io-protocol#packet) doesn't seem to specify the wire format, and the identifiers don't seem to match up with those used by `gevent-socketio`.

Is there a definitive wire format? Is it possible to write a Socket.IO-compatible server, maybe for some fixed version of the protocol, with a fixed/known client library?

Comment: Interesting question and this is not too broad at all (as some have voted to close) as there should be a single fact-based answer.  I was curious also, but I can't myself find the true over-the-wire format either.  I think this is a bit because socket.io runs on top of some other protocol (http long polling, websocket, etc...) so that complicates the actual format a bit.  But, it certainly should be possible to find the socket.io format though I didn't find it in my own search.  It has to be out there somewhere.

Comment: I'd be very interested in a C++ server API, preferably based on boost

Comment: This may or may not be an answer but I would suggest to use WebSocket protocol instead.

Comment: check this project https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-cpp

Comment: There's also this project which purports to be a server, not a client.  It looks a bit old/undeveloped but might have some useful code: https://github.com/pnxs/socket.io-serverpp

Comment: If this question is about web, the most elaborated library at hand is probably `boost.beast`: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_79_0/libs/beast/doc/html/index.html

Answer (score -4):

The Socket.IO protocol is used to encode and decode the messages that are exchanged between the client and the server. The messages are sent in the form of packets, which are encoded using a specific wire format.

The packet format used by gevent-socketio consists of a packet type identifier (e.g., 5), a packet id (e.g., 1), and the packet data (e.g., {"name": "tobi"}). The packet type identifier specifies the type of packet being sent (e.g., event, acknowledgement, etc.), and the packet id is used for message acknowledgement and for identifying specific packets.

*Your answer*

It is possible to write a Socket.IO-compatible server in C++, but you will need to implement the Socket.IO protocol and wire format yourself. You will also need to ensure that your server is compatible with the client library that you are using. It is generally recommended to use a Socket.IO client library that is compatible with the version of the Socket.IO protocol that you are using on the server side.